# C# read data from gridView to string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Hey I have a gridView and I would like to extract the PhotoPath (ftppath + filename (ftp://192.168.1.2/Jelly.jpg))

its in asp.net and I'm not sure how to retrieve the data ive set the gridView up for selection and I like to "upon" select store the PhotoPath in a string.

source

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="StudentID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="263px" Width="915px" 
        AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="No" HeaderText="MatricNo" 
                SortExpression="MatricNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Current" HeaderText="CurrentModules" 
                SortExpression="CurrentModules" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PhotoPath" HeaderText="PhotoPath" 
                SortExpression="PhotoPath" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            Font-Size="Small" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
            Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I tryed this:

```
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PhotoPath;
        GridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

But current row isn't part of the definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string PhotoPath = "";
    // Get the currently selected row. Because the SelectedIndexChanging event
    // occurs before the select operation in the GridView control, the
    // SelectedRow property cannot be used. Instead, use the Rows collection
    // and the NewSelectedIndex property of the e argument passed to this 
    // event handler.
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

    PhotoPath = row.Cells[5].Text;
}
```

or

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string PhotoPath = "";
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    PhotoPath = row.Cells[5].Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) getting a small error with NewSelectedIndex tho     Error 1 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'NewSelectedIndex' and no extension method 'NewSelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: To get the index of the newly-selected row, you need to handle the SelectedIndexChanging event instead. Then e should have the NewSelectedIndex property.

Comment: oops! You're right! Sorry for that. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: yup its ok got it :) maybe you could take a look at my newest post, very disturbing lol